# c# unity calling method using reflection on proxy

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, proxy, aop

I'm stucked on one problem. I'm having piece of code like this:

```
ITest test= ObtainObject(); //ObtainObjectimplementation omitted
Type type = test.GetType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Display");
method.Invoke(test, new object[] {"hi"});

interface ITest {
    [LoggerAspect]
    Display(String msg);
}

class Test : ITest 
{
    public void Display(String msg) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);   
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I replace

```
method.Invoke(test, new object[] {"hi"});
```

with

```
test.Display("Hi")
```

everything, including aspect, works fine. The test is an proxy object and if I call the invoke on that proxy it throws me

```
TargetException: Object does not match target type
```

The issue is I need to use reflection, has any of you ever faced such a problem?
Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

Why the `Display` method in the interface doesn't have any return type defined? I think that shouldn't even compile in the first place.

You should also consider showing the `ObtainObject` code, so we can know exactly how are you getting the interface. Other than that, I think I can't do very much.

Comment: Display method is void type - I just wrote it here incorrectly... The ObtainObject does something like this: ITest ObtainObject() {return Program.UnityContainer.Resolve<ITest>(); }

Comment: and from unity context it obtains proxy object - thats good, but when I try to call method on that aspect using reflection it doesn't work...

Comment: I just tested your code and it seems to run OK, the only thing I can think of now is that you may be casting your class to the interface in a wrong way. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/C73eic0Q